# Calculate cloud instance aws Ec2 uptime by Cloud metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

can we calculate AWS Ec2 instance uptime, downtime or (availability)  by using or analyzing the Cloud watch metrics?
Is that possible?
if not, How do I calculate the uptime percentage for My ec2 instance?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

No its not. CloudWatch does not monitor uptime status of your instance. You need to develop a [custom metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) from that which originates from your instance or application.